# Idiomatic way of handling optional values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development and also Swift. I'm working on a project consisting of a menu that leads to my various experimentations with the iOS SDK.

I've written the menu titles and `segueIdentifiers` in a plist and I'm populating an array of `NavigationItem` in `viewDidLoad()`.

Is the following code idiomatic, particularly in the way it handles optional values? What might be better?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NavigationMenu", ofType: "plist")

        if path == nil{
            NSLog("Unable to locate file : NavigationMenu.plist")
            return
        }

        let items = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)

        if items == nil {
            NSLog("Navigation menu items could not be read from plist.")
            return
        }

        for var i = 0 ; i < items!.count ; i++ {

            let item : NSDictionary = items!.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary
            navigationItems.append(NavigationItem(
                name:(item.objectForKey("name") as! String),
                andSegueIdentifier: (item.objectForKey("segueIdentifier") as! String)
                ))

        }

    }
```

Comment: Does `pathForResource` return `NSURL!` or `NSURL?` and same question for everything else here that might return `nil`?

Comment: `pathForResource` returns `String?`. `NSArray(contentsOfFile)` returns `[AnyObject]?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better way to handle optional values is "optional binding":

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NavigationMenu", ofType: "plist") {
    // do something with `path`
} else {
    NSLog("Unable to locate file : NavigationMenu.plist")
}
```

which tests *and* unwraps the optional result as a single action.
Inside the if-block, `path` is the unwrapped `String`.

You can do the same with the items:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NavigationMenu", ofType: "plist") {
    if let items = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
        // do something with `items` ...
    } else {
        NSLog("Navigation menu items could not be read from plist.")
    }
} else {
    NSLog("Unable to locate file : NavigationMenu.plist")
}
```

As of Swift 1.2, multiple optional bindings can be combined in
a single if-statement, which reduces the number of nested if-levels:

```
if
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NavigationMenu", ofType: "plist"),
    let items = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
        // do something with `items` ...
} else {
    NSLog("Unable to load NavigationMenu")
}
```

The downside is that you have only a common else-block for the
error condition and cannot distinguish which of the optional bindings
failed.

Instead of `objectAtIndex()` and `objectForKey()` you can use 
subscripting for `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`:

```
for var i = 0 ; i < items!.count ; i++ {
    let item = items![i] as! NSDictionary
    let navItem = NavigationItem(name: item["name"] as! String,
        andSegueIdentifier: item["segueIdentifier"] as! String)
    navigationItems.append(navItem)
}
```

But a better way is to cast the `NSArray` to a Swift array of Swift dictionaries in the first step.
Then you can use array enumeration and don't need any casts later:

```
if
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NavigationMenu", ofType: "plist"),
    let items = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String : String]] {

        for item in items {
            let navItem = NavigationItem(name: item["name"]!, andSegueIdentifier: item["segueIdentifier"]!)
            navigationItems.append(navItem)
        }
} else {
    NSLog("Unable to load NavigationMenu")
}
```

This assumes that values for the "name" and "segueIdentifier" are
present (and will crash at runtime otherwise). Alternatively, use
optional binding again:

```
for item in items {
    if let name = item["name"], ident = item["segueIdentifier"] {
        let navItem = NavigationItem(name: name, andSegueIdentifier: ident)
        navigationItems.append(navItem)
    } else {
        NSLog("Invalid navigation item")
    }
}
```

Finally, you could replace the inner loop by a `map()` operation:

```
if
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NavigationMenu", ofType: "plist"),
    let items = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String : String]] {
        navitationItems = map(items) {
            NavigationItem(name: $0["name"]!, andSegueIdentifier: $0["segueIdentifier"]!)
        }
} else {
    NSLog("Unable to load NavigationMenu")
}
```

Comment: This is a terrific answer! I didn't know you could do multiple optional bindings with a single if else statement. The large number of nested statement is what put me off